# Разбиение на области

Tags: opencv

Добрый день, занимаюсь разработкой системы распознования Российских номеров с открытым исходным кодов.

Перекурил множество мануалов, но не нашёл ответа на интересующий меня вопрос: Имеется обрезанное изображение(см. изображение 1)  на нём есть цифры и буквы, нужно получить примерно результаты как на изображение 2.
Изображение 1:
http://rghost.ru/56601643/image.png

Изображение 2:

http://habrastorage.org/getpro/habr/post_images/2a1/c38/33d/2a1c3833d25dea548501f2851c9eadc8.png

Есть ли статьи или методы в которых можно найти что-то подобное?

был вариант обучить каскад хаара, но думаю, что это будет слишком "мощно" для конкретной задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Способов много, например:

- бинаризация изображения (метод Оцу)
- поиск связных компонент (обход графа: поиск в ширину/глубину)
- нахождение ограничивающих прямоугольников (bounding box) для каждой компоненты связности
- объединение пресекающихся компонент
- дальше уже каждая полученная компонента это отдельная буква, тогда надо будет заняться распознаванием символов. Но это уже другая тема.

Вообще очень много статей на Хабре по поводу распознавания автомобильных номеров. Вот например одна из них: [Распознавание автомобильных номеров в деталях](http://habrahabr.ru/company/recognitor/blog/225913/)